# テンプレート「Train Catalog」でリストから参照される画像を全画面表示したい

Tags: monaca, css

Monaca 新規プロジェクトから選択できるテンプレートの "Train Catalog" で、リストから参照される電車の画像には、上下左右に余白があります。

[image: 画像の余白]

この余白をなくし画像を表示することは可能でしょうか？

```html
<div data-role="page" id="tokaido-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="jqm-header-custom" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Train Catalog</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Tokaido Shinkansen Trains</li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="showDetail('0kei', 'Series 0')">Series 0</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS は以下のようになっています。

```
display: block;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

ページ自体が `padding: 15`, イメージが `margin: 0 5 0 5` を持っているので、それらの値を `0px` にします。

```html
<div data-role="page" id="detail-page">
```

を

```html
<div data-role="page" id="detail-page" class="train-page">
```

に変えて、 `style.css` に以下を追加してください。

```css
.train-page {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}

.train-page .ui-content {
    padding: 0px;
}

.train-page .ui-content #train-image {
    margin: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: 教えていただいた方法で解決できました。
ありがとうございました！

Comment: @user8011 本回答で解決した場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers